# Summarized Value and Grand Total are wrong in PowerBI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working with claims where I use different key joins/sheets to get the whole truth.
Right now I got two different sheets with costs for each item (Price Per Unit), depending on where the repair occur. One for Asia and one for the rest of the world (WW)

*Sheet 1: PN-List Asia* **and** *Sheet 2: PN-List WW*

Inside the mentioned sheets there is a priority (1 - 3) of which supplier I should get prices from.
Column *Prio*.

I've made a column that either says Asia or WW for each job ID. *Regress List [Continent]*.

Two problem has occurred, total cost for each ID is only the max value (most expensive item). See picture: [image: First Problem]

The total cost should be: 840,96 but it says 622,10 now.

The second problem is that my grand total is completely wrong, should be a lot more. See below picture:

[image: Problem 2]

The formula I've used:

```
    Price Per unit =
IF (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Regress List'[Continent] ) = "Asia",
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'PN-List Asia'[Price Per Unit] ),
        FILTER ( 'PN-List Asia', 'PN-List Asia'[Prio] = MIN ( 'PN-List Asia'[Prio] ) )
    ),
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'PN-List WW'[Price Per Unit] ),
        FILTER ( 'PN-List WW', 'PN-List WW'[Prio] = MIN ( 'PN-List WW'[Prio] ) )
    )
)
```

Comment: Your Dax measure calculates only the maximum price per unit in the filter context where [Prio] column value in tables 'PN-List Asia' and 'PN_List WW' is equal to min. I think you should need an iterator function 'SUMX' to scan row by row , then reach the correct grand total.

Comment: Honestly not sure how I solved it but created a new measure with: 

Price Per Units = SUMX('Regress List', 'Regress List'[Qty] * [Price Per unit])

And it gave me the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a new measure:

Price Per Units = SUMX('Regress List', 'Regress List'[Qty] * [Price Per unit])

And it gave me the right answer

Thanks to Ozan Sen for leading me in the right way with Sumx

Comment: Bingo, super  I am pleased to hear that you have solved your problem.